# SQL Server : randomize rows (shuffle IDs)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a way to randomize the rows in SQL Server?

I don't want to retrieve the rows in a random manner, I know how to to that.

I want to shuffle the row IDs in the database (ex. ID1 will change to ID27 and ID27 will change to ID1).

I can copy all records to a temporary table, truncate the original table and insert the records back from the temporary table using a parallel loop for randomization.

Is there an easier way to this ?

ID is the identity seed, auto incremented

Comment: What is an ID for your situation ? Is it a column containing auto incremental integers ? Is it the PK too ? Please be more specific

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you like to do that to begin with?

Comment: ID is the identity seed, auto incremented (no PK).

Comment: You **cannot** update an `IDENTITY` column - you can only insert new values overriding the `IDENTITY` mechanism

Comment: Your own method (copy all rows to temp table, truncate original table, copy all rows back in random order) is quite efficient (maybe the most efficient) and I would use it, even if your IDs were not `IDENTITY` and you could update them. You also mention "parallel loop" and I don't understand why. You don't need explicit loops to do this. Actually, you can do it even better: copy all rows into a new table with temp name in a random order, drop original table, rename temp table.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov: How can I copy the rows in a random order ? Do I select them using NEWID or is there another way ?

Comment: @user3307685, you wrote in the question that you know how to retrieve rows in a random manner, so I didn't elaborate. This is one possible variant to copy rows from `OldTable` into the `NewTable` in a random order: `INSERT INTO NewTable SELECT ... FROM OldTable ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)` In SQL Server before 2008 you can use `NEWID` instead of `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`.

Comment: @user3307685, You can do without temp table, but IDs would change. At first find MaxID in the table. Copy the table into itself. `INSERT INTO YourTable SELECT ... FROM YourTable WHERE ID <= MaxID ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)` All `IDENTITY` IDs would become larger than before. Then `DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE ID <= MaxID`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a really strange requirement. Since the id is an identity you can't change that, so you'll have to swap all the other data on the row, which you could probably do with something like this:

```
select
  a.id as old_id,
  b.*
into #newdata
from
  (
    select 
      id, 
      row_number() over (order by id) as rn 
    from 
      data
  ) a
  join (
     select 
      *, 
      row_number() over (order by newid()) as rn 
    from 
      data
  ) b on a.rn = b.rn
```

This creates a temp table with old and new id numbers + all the columns from the table. You could then use to update all the columns for the rows from in the original table using this temp. table.

Can't really recommend doing this, especially if there's a lot of rows. Before doing this you probably should take a table level exclusive lock to the table just in case.